# How to return vector of enum outside the class?

Tags: c++, vector, enums

Lets say A class has 2d vector of enum and I want to access this 2d vector outside of the class and manipulate the value.

My Question is : How can I declare the new vector to hold the return by value outside of the class, since my type ( enum type) is inside the class? I was hoping to some thing like

```
A a(5);
std::vector<std::vector<A::s> > x = a.get_2dvec();
```

But this give me error saying its private and then if I make type public I get not declared error.

I know I could place  enum s {RED, BLUE, GREEN}; and typedef s color; outside of class and achieve the result but lets say the main is on different file.

```
 // f1.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class A{
    // This enum is inside class 
    enum s {RED, BLUE, GREEN};
    typedef s color;
    const int size = 3;
    std::vector<std::vector<color> > color_array;
public:
    A(int size_):size(size_),color_array(size){
        std::cout << "vector size  = " << color_array.size() << std::endl;
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < size; j++){
                color_array[i].push_back(RED);
            }
        }  
    }
    void print(){
        for(auto it = color_array.begin(); it != color_array.end(); it++){
            for(auto itt = it->begin(); itt != it->end(); itt++){
                std::cout << *itt << " : " << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }

    // pass vector by value
    std::vector<std::vector<color> > get_2dvec(){
        return color_array;
    }
};

// main.cpp
int main(){
    A a(4);
    a.print();
    // here I some how need to capture the 2d enum vector
    std::vector<std::vector<enum-type> > x = get_2dvec();



return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why return by value? If `color_array` has to be manipulated outside the `class` then return by reference, otherwise return by `const` reference. You can use **`auto`** keyword, if you don't want to make `A::s` as `public`, but I am not sure, how far will it help. BTW, once you make `public`, you will have to access the enum values as `A::RED`, `A::BLUE` and so on. What exact error are you getting?

Comment: @iammilind So far auto solved the problem. So the reason I was passing by value is that I will be passing this vector to each node of the tree and each node of the tree will evaluate each elements of the vector separately (I hope that makes sense .. similar to tictactoe minimax tree).

Comment: Even in that case also, you should return by const reference. Later receive by value to make a copy. It will give you flexibility when the copy is not required. i.e. use `auto&` to receive by reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`get_2dvec()` is a member function, which needs an object to call on it. And if you don't want to make `A::s` `public`, you could use [auto specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) (since C++11) to avoid accessing private name directly. (But I'm not sure whether this is what you want.)

Change

```
std::vector<std::vector<enum-type> > x = get_2dvec();
```

to

```
auto x = a.get_2dvec();
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for .. I was using auto in iterator but for some reason I didn't figure that out. My be the private member thing and compiler error confused me

Comment: not the point but interface will be better off with constant references (which would allow to write `const auto &x = a.get_2dvec();` and would save memory copy.

Comment: @pokche The effect of using `auto` is limited, there're still some cases couldn't be solved by it. If it's fine for your design, then no problem. If not, you might consider again to make `A::s` or `A::color` `public`.

Answer (score 2):

Your enum is in the private part of the class.

By default, a `class` starts by default in `private`, whereas a `struct` starts by default in `public`.

Move it to the public part

In addition, return the value by reference, in a constant getter method or performance and interface quality in general will suffer.

I would typedef the matrix itself too, and use it at once in the class, thus leading me to put the private part in the end.

Edit: since answering questions also means learning stuff from others, I have fully refactored the example with const references, auto, all types private, all the works, just for the record (and it builds).

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class A
{
private:
    // This enum is inside class 
    const int size = 3;
    enum s {RED, BLUE, GREEN};
    typedef s color;
    typedef std::vector<std::vector<color> > ColorMatrix;
    ColorMatrix color_array;
public:
    A(int size_):size(size_),color_array(size){
        std::cout << "vector size  = " << color_array.size() << std::endl;
        for(auto &it : color_array){
            it.resize(size,RED);
           }

    }
    void print() const{
        for(const auto &it : color_array){
            std::cout << " :";
            for(const auto &itt : it){
                std::cout << " " << itt;
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    }

    // pass vector by const reference to avoid copies
   // (for better performance)
    const ColorMatrix &get_2dvec() const {
        return color_array;
    }

};

// main.cpp
int main(){
    A a(4);
    a.print();
    // here I some how need to capture the 2d enum vector
    const auto &x = a.get_2dvec();



return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note: `auto` allows to use private types declared inside the class by clients.

Comment: @Jean-Francois Fabre I like you answer but I still wanted the ColorMatrix to be private so I think auto is the way to go.

Comment: no problem. BTW I refactored your code a lot apart from that, you should check the constructors and const methods and all the auto stuff I have added.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Just pointing out the obvious  .. the comment on the const ColorMatrix &get_2dvec() const { return color_array; } says // pass vector by value ... I am guessing you meant to say // pass vector by reference  ( It might have been copied from my comment)  Just saying :)